# JPA - Specificaton with in clause and case insensitive

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

using mysql and springboot jpa,

I am trying to implement in clause using JPA.when the parameters list passed to specification, get expected results when written manaul query like below.
the employeeId is a string column with have both capital and small letters.
though the manual query works but a specification have to be implemented.

Manual query :

```
SELECT emp
FROM EmployeeEntitiy emp
WHERE LOWER(emp.employeeIdParam) IN(
  SELECT LOWER(empRel.destinationssid)
  FROM EmployeeRelationEntity empRel WHERE ((LOWER(empRel.employeeId)=:employeeIdParam
                                             OR UPPER(empRel.employeeId)=:employeeIdParam)
                                             OR empRel.employeeId=:employeeIdParam)
```

how can i check the column data with both capital and small like the manual query in **toPredicate** overriden method.
JPA Specification:

```
private class ParentChildCISpecification implements Specification<EmployeeEntitiy> {
    List<String> employeeIdParamsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ParentChildCISpecification(List<String> employeeIdParamsList) {
        this.employeeIdParamsList = employeeIdParamsList;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<EmployeeEntitiy> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

        return root.get("employeeId").in(employeeIdParamsList);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the query with IgnoreCase?

Answer (score 5):

Pass in a lowercased String list and use `CriteriaBuilder.lower` expression:

```
@Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<EmployeeEntitiy> root
        , CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

        return criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("employeeId")).in(employeeIdParamsList);

    }
```

Comment: hi machiej thanks for the answer,    employeeIdParamsList.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase); criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get("employeeId")).in(employeeIdParamsList); and tried with lower also still not able to retrieve the record. what i noticed by manual query is parameter retreived in list is in small letter and the table column value is with mixed upper and lower case letters

Comment: Have you tried modifying the hibernate configuration to print the generated query?

Answer (score 4):

In case of the equal following can be used

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;

final Specification<EmployeeEntity> spec = (employeeEntity, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(cb.lower(employeeEntity.get("email")), email.toLowerCase());
final List<EmployeeEntity> empList = employeeRepository.findAll(spec, PageRequest.of(page, size));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE EmployeeEntitiy` -- You may find that the `COLLATION` is `...bin` instead of `...ci` (for "Case Insensitive")